# How to deal with excessive requests on heroku

Tags: heroku, python-requests

I am experiencing a once per 60-90 minute spike in traffic that's causing my Heroku app to slow to a crawl for the duration of the spike - NewRelic is reporting response times of 20-50 seconds per request, with 99% of that down to the Heroku router queuing requests up. The request count goes from an average of around 50-100rpm up to 400-500rpm

Looking at the logs, it looks to me like a scraping bot or spider trying to access a lot of content pages on the site. However it's not all coming from a single IP.

What can I do about it?

My sysadmin / devops skills are pretty minimal.

Guy

Answer (score 0):

Have your host based firewall throttle those requests. Depending on your setup, you can also add Nginx in to the mix, which can throttle requests too.